# Write text into input field with a PHP variable

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, variables

I would like to write in an input field with a PHP variable. This is the current code I have:

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function reply(form, inp){
    form.texta.value = "@" + inp;
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
 <a href="#" onClick="reply(form1, <?php echo $poster; ?>);">Reply ^</a>

 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="index.php"><input type="texta" name="texta" /></form>
```

This code however does not put the text of the variable in the input field. Sorry, I am a bit new to JavaScript.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Is there any error you faced?

Comment: You had to enclose the $poster variable inside quotes, in order to be treated as text!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using my code I gave in the question and due to the answers/comments i have put single quotes around the php, and now it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" onClick="reply(form1, '<?php echo $poster; ?>');">Reply ^</a>
```

EDIT : You should  Give `Id` to text box.

Comment: still does not work for me, the text does not get into the field.

Comment: document.getElementById('texta').value = "@" + inp; in javascript

Answer (score 0):

if you want it direct

```
<input type="texta" name="texta" value="<?=$poster?>" />
```

Or

```
use document.form.texta.value = value
```

or like this

```
document.forms["form"]["texta"].value = value
```

put any of these inside

```
function reply(form, inp){

}

<a href="#" onClick="reply(form1,"<?=$poster?>");">Reply ^</a>
```

Comment: not possible, the variable is inside a while loop after the input field is created.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="texta" value="<?php echo $poster; ?>" />
```

Comment: not possible, the variable is inside a while loop after the input field is created.